# Extracting normalised sample python

Tags: python-3.x, dataset, extract

I need to extract 1% sample from a 1 Billion database. This 1% should be equally distributed on a numeric variable. For example if the dataset has 1000 rows and the numeric variable has values 1-10 then the output sample has a dataset having each row of each value.

Comment: This seems more like a statistical sampling question than a programming question.  However, is spite of having worked a decade as a statistician, I do not understand your question.  I suggest rewording in multiple sentences, with more detail.

Comment: Hope its more clear now :)

Comment: Not enough yet., Sorry.  What do you have a billion of?  What do you want to sample?  What sort of 'database'?  Text file? RDBMS? I still do not understand 'equally distributed on a numeric variable' and 'dataset having each row of each value'.  We seem to have learned different ways of phrasing things.

Comment: Okay, lets make it simple. Suppose I just need a 1% subset of data such that it is a true representation of the whole data-set. Is there any way I can get that in python? 
I hope its better now :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to program any standard sampling scheme in Python using the `random` module.

You last comment describes a [simple random sample](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_random_sample).  Thinking more, I believe your previous comments describe [stratfied sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratified_sampling).  Whether stratified sampling is a good idea or not depends on your questions and the data.  Statistical analysis should match sampling method.  However, these issues are out of scope for stackoverflow.

If you try to program a particular method and have a particular programming problem, then asking about it here would be on-topic.